# Is it possible to print the JUnit output in Netbeans to the console?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

JUnit in Netbeans prints the output of failed tests in **one line**. Long error messages are hardly readable.

**Example:**
[image]

Is it possible to print the output to the console or format this message in another way?

Comment: I'd argue that this depends on the IDE, but how many tests are you running?

Comment: A lot tests. I work with test driven development.

Comment: Make the view wider, or your sentences shorter? Without writing your own runner, I don't see how. You might be able to run your tests as an external tool using Ant/Maven/etc. and get *that* output in the console.